# Removing whitespace in hover

Tags: html, css, webshop

Good morning,

I need some help removing the whitespace on a hover. The code is as following and i added a screenshot.

```
div.show_sizes_onhover {
background: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
bottom: -1px;
color: #a1a1a1;
left: 0;
padding: 5px;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
width: 95%;
z-index: 9999;
```

I tried to play around with margin/height a bit, but it's not working properly. Thanks in advance.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a9Ut.jpg)

Comment: This is not enough code to go on.

Comment: Do not edit your question to remove the text once your issue is solved; leave the question in place and accept the answer which helped you *or* write your own answer in order that you might help others in future with a similar issue. If you write your own answer then accept that - if it remains the most helpful solution - in two days, once you're allowed to do so.

Answer (score 2):

try using

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

it should remove the whitespace, 
you can also use

```
white-space: normal;
```

the difrences are written [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Comment: Thanks, but it was a class that was still showing. Fixed it!